# Why does text selection not work in MacCatalyst app's WKWebView on macOS Sonoma Only

Tags: wkwebview, mac-catalyst, macos-sonoma

Can not select anything within WkWebView editor view of my MacCatalyst app when running on macOS 14 Sonoma.

Any selection gesture or command key fails to select anything in **content editable WKWebView**, so none of the Editor tools can be activated.

My application uses the nnhubbard / ZSSRichTextEditor **WKWebView**-based Rich Text Editor:  https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor. The app is built with Xcode 15.0 or 15.0.1.

The app is a **Catalyst** app that implements an editor view with a ZSSRichTextEditor **WKWebView**.

The problem does not occur if the the app is run in **iOS** or **macOS 11, 12, or 13** (**Catalina, Monterey, or Ventura**.)  The issue only occurs in **macOS 14 Sonoma**.

The following error message is logged whenever an attempt to select any text in the WKWebView content:

0x1359ecc18 - [pageProxyID=14, webPageID=15, PID=14,932] WebPageProxy::didFailProvisionalLoadForFrame: frameID=1, isMainFrame=1, domain=NSURLErrorDomain, code=18,446,744,073,709,550,614, isMainFrame=1, willInternallyHandleFailure=0